# Poedit is not working after update to v2.0

Tags: translation, poedit

I've just updated Poedit to the currently newest version 2.0 (4948). Now I'm observing two issues on with update of the source strings (button <kbd>Update</kbd>):

- No new source strings are added to the list -- they seem just to be ignored.
- If I remove a string, this is also ignored -- the string remains in the *.po file.
- Many strings (first of all the strings starting with a varialbe like `%s`) disappear.

How to get it working correctly again?

---

**EDIT**

Just downgraded Poedit (removed v2.0 and installed v1.5.7), but the issue is still there. So obviously it's not a version 2 problem. (Though I let the question title unchanged, since it might be an updated related.)

Comment: You have misconfigured extraction, such as missing keywords, simple as that. Since you don't share any relevant details, it's impossible to know what exactly it is.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I don't know which details would be relevant. What should I share?

Comment: You have a problem with a specific PO file. Self-evidently said file is highly relevant. But really, just add the keywords to the setup.

Comment: Which keywords? To which setup? Sorry, what do you mean?